# jQuery send post variable using ajax and submit form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I have html form with dynamical number of fields, for example:

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
<input type="text" id="input3">
...
<input type="text" id="inputN">
<span id="button_click"> CLICK </span>
</form>
```

and jQuery which is:

```
  $("#button_click").click(function(){

    $.post("myfile.php",
    {
      XXXX:YYYY
    },
    function(data,status){
      // do anyting
    });

  });
```

I don't know the exact number of fields, so I can't fill XXXX - post variable name, and YYYY - field data from web page.... so I can't count/write one by one...

How can I submit whole form, through post variables, using AJAX and click button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the `.serialize()` method:

```
$.post("myfile.php",
$("#myform").serialize(),
function(data,status){
    // do anyting
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 1):

```
//rough code for general puporse of storing values for post
var obj = $("#myform"),
data = {};//to hold the values
obj.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    name = obj.attr('name'),
    value = obj.val();
    data[name] = value;
});
$.post("myfile.php",
    data: data,
    function(data,status){
      // do anyting
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your decision, it is good way to get data and send it via post variable.  I will try it... Thank you!